# Parse errors with data.table fread

Tags: r, data.table, bioinformatics, fread

I'm running into some parse errors reading tables from the UCSC genome browser. There looks to be a combination of sparse initial rows and ubiquitous quotes causing problems.

Two examples: [first](http://hgdownload.soe.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg19/database/gadAll.txt.gz), [second](http://hgdownload.soe.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg19/database/refLink.txt.gz).

There were some similar previous posts but nothing seemed to specifically address these tests. 
Using data.table v1.9.3 from rforge.

Ideas?

Comment: data.table has moved to github. Please test with the newest version from [there](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/).

Comment: Agreed. Several recent fixes in that area. Definitely worth installing from GitHub.

Comment: @MattDowle You should change the link in your SO user profile. It would also be good to change the links on CRAN, but I realise that's not so easy. But could you place a forward link on r-forge?

Comment: Could you post lines of how it is parsed now, how is the original file and how do you want it, and if you include how do you do it it will be much better, thanks!

Comment: @Roland. Have edited profile and will do re R-Forge page, good call, thanks.